# What is __alldiv?

Tags: c++, crash, visual-c++-6, divide-by-zero

I receive error reports with a Division by zero crash, and the crash occurs at a function called __alldiv. This function is not called anywhere in my code, I searched for it with Find in files.

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482624/using-64-bits-integers-without-c-runtime-link-error-alldiv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__alldiv` is the function from Visual Studio C runtime library which handles 64-bit integer division in 32-bit environment, it looks similar to this: http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/source/lib/lldiv.asm.html

Answer (score 3):

`__alldiv` is MSVC's integer division function.

When you emit an integer division in your code, it doesn't always map one-to-one to the `div` or `idiv` assembly instruction. This is due to differences between the language specified behavior and the actual behavior of the `div` and `idiv` instructions.

Therefore MSVC invokes a function call to its own integer division function.